# Add, remove, and test for the existence of a registry value * at the Command Prompt?

Tags: batch-file, windows-registry, windows-command-prompt

I am trying to check and update the network zone mapping in the registry from the Command Prompt. I need to check for the value named `*`. For example, under *HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\ZoneMap\Domains\cmich.local*, Registry Editor shows the following:

`*  REG_DWORD   0x00000001 (1)`

To check this value in a command script (*.cmd), I have been attempting to use the REG QUERY command. When I attempt to do so by passing `*` as the value to match, the REG QUERY command treats the asterisk as a wildcard and returns a match as long as the key exists.

```
reg query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\ZoneMap\Domains\example.com" /v "*" /reg:64
```

I've tried numerous combinations of escape characters (even those that I was pretty sure wouldn't work), including all of the following with and without quotation marks: `*`, `\*`, `^*`, `` `* ``, `` `*` ``, `!*`. None of these worked.

I also need to add and remove values with the name `*`, presumably with REG ADD and REG DELETE.

How do I add, remove, and test for the existence of a registry value with the name `*` at the Command Prompt?

Comment: Is Powershell an option?

Comment: I ran into the same trouble using PowerShell's Get-Item cmdlet on the registry key and trying to extract the properties. I can't find a syntax that makes the cmdlet use * as the name of the registry value rather than as a wildcard.

Comment: Did you try in Powershell with `-LiteralPath` ? `Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Classes\*\shell"` and possibly piping the proper value to Remove-Item?

Answer (score 1):

The tricky part of checking a registry value named `*` (actually a wildcard of meaning *all*):

- query only one-character named values using `?` wildcard i.e. *at most one character*, and
- narrow the result to the value named `*` using [`findstr` utility](https://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html);

  - in fact, `reg query "%_TestKey%" /v ? | findstr /I /C:"    *    REG_"` could suffice.

The following batch-file code snippet shows that there is no issue with adding, removing or changing a value named `*`.

The code is *commented* using `<NUL set /P =::: …` trick i.e. `echo ::: …` with no ending <kbd>CR</kbd><kbd>LF</kbd> to show comments in output with minimum of empty lines.

```
@ECHO ON
@SETLOCAL EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
@<NUL set /P =::: define a registry key
set "_TestKey=HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Test Key"
@<NUL set /P =::: check all one-character named values 
reg query "%_TestKey%" /v ?
@<NUL set /P =::: narrow above result to the value named * using findstr utility 
reg query "%_TestKey%" /v ? | findstr /I /C:"%_TestKey%" /C:"    *    REG_"
@<NUL set /P =::: delete the value named *
reg delete "%_TestKey%" /v * /f
@<NUL set /P =::: add the value named *
reg add "%_TestKey%" /v * /t REG_DWORD /d 4 /f
@<NUL set /P =::: check the value named * 
reg query "%_TestKey%" /v ? | findstr /I /C:"%_TestKey%" /C:"    *    REG_"
@<NUL set /P =::: change the value named *
reg add "%_TestKey%" /v * /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f
@<NUL set /P =::: check the value named * 
reg query "%_TestKey%" /v ? | findstr /I /C:"%_TestKey%" /C:"    *    REG_"
```

**Output**:

```
==> D:\bat\SF\a867740.bat
::: define a registry key
==> set "_TestKey=HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Test Key"
::: check all one-character named values
==> reg query "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Test Key" /v ?

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Test Key
    a    REG_SZ    Latin Small Letter A
    .    REG_SZ    Full Stop
    ?    REG_SZ    Question Mark
    *    REG_DWORD    0x1

End of search: 4 match(es) found.
::: narrow above result to the value named * using findstr utility
==> reg query "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Test Key" /v ?   | findstr /I /C:"HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Test Key" /C:"    *    REG_"
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Test Key
    *    REG_DWORD    0x1
::: delete the value named *
==> reg delete "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Test Key" /v * /f
The operation completed successfully.
::: add the value named *
==> reg add "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Test Key" /v * /t REG_DWORD /d 4 /f
The operation completed successfully.
::: check the value named *
==> reg query "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Test Key" /v ?   | findstr /I /C:"HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Test Key" /C:"    *    REG_"
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Test Key
    *    REG_DWORD    0x4
::: change the value named *
==> reg add "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Test Key" /v * /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f
The operation completed successfully.
::: check the value named *
==> reg query "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Test Key" /v ?   | findstr /I /C:"HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Test Key" /C:"    *    REG_"
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Test Key
    *    REG_DWORD    0x1
```